# Dash line in the middle of a folder name

Tags: bash

One of the main folders in my computer is named as "OneDrive - University of XXX". I have been trying to access it from the command line with low success. I think the problem is on the "-" in the middle.

I use the command `-ls` to show the files and I can see that "OneDrive - University of XXX" is there. If I type "OneD" and then use tab/autocompletion, I can see both folders, but the response to "OneDrive - University of XXX" is `-bash: cd: /OneDrive: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem are rather the spaces. Assuming your quotes in the questions are just for formatting and you do not actually put the argument for `cd` in quotes.

`cd OneDrive\ -\ University of XXX` or if this does not work, put it in quotes: `cd "OneDrive - University of XXX"`. Both work for me in a git bash on Windows 10 which should also be working for you then I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Another neat trick is to use the `tab` function when accessing folder or file names. Just type `cd One` then hit `tab` twice and the required back slashes will be added automatically. Always great and helpful to remember this.

Comment: That’s what I did to discover the solution with the backslashes. I didn’t know about `\ `, I would have just used quotes.